# Rome getAuthor() always returns empty string. Why?

Tags: rss, rome

I am parsing RSS Feeds with Rome. The getAuthor method returns null every time, and getAuthors returns an empty list. I am using Rome 1.0. Everything I see online says the same thing and it all seems quite simple. Before I pull down the source and step into it, I thought Id ask here to see if I am missing something simple.
Why is Rome not finding the author?

here is my code:

URL url = new URL("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/topNews");
    XmlReader reader = null;

```
try {

  reader = new XmlReader(url);
  SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedInput(true).build(reader);
  System.out.println("Feed Title: " + feed.getTitle());
  List<SyndEntry> entries = feed.getEntries();
  for (SyndEntry entry: entries) {
    System.out.println(entry.getTitleEx().getValue());
    entry.getAuthor();
   // System.out.println(entry);
    System.out.println("DEC: " + entry.getDescription().getValue() + "\nDEC");
    System.out.println(entry.getPublishedDate());
   // System.out.println(entry.getTitle());
    System.out.println("\n\n");

  }
} finally {
  if (reader != null) {
    reader.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no authors in your Reuters feed. Maybe try some other feed?

Comment: life is hard, but it's harder when you're stupid.........like me. thanks janih  that was the problem. Other feeds return an author just fine.